# How do I minify inline CSS using Twig?

Tags: theming, 8

Inside my html.html.twig template I've added a stylesheet inside the style elements using this.

```
{% include directory ~ '/css/base/style.css' %}
```

Is there a way that I can strip it for all whitespaces? Can I apply the CssOptimizer class to it in any way? Can I also strip the stylesheet for comments?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way to integrate a .css file inside a twig file in drupal8. You should use the standard procedure as I mentioned below.

```
 {{ attach_library('bartik/messages') }}
```

SO now for minifying the .css  you can use the 3rd party site- https://cssminifier.com/

So the after minifying the .css file, crate the library

```
messages:
  css:
    theme:
      css/components/my-minify.css: {}
```

Then attach the library in the twig by using the below sysntax

```
{{ attach_library('your-theme-name/messages') }}
```

Hope this will help you. If any doubt please don't hesitate to mention.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, i know abour it. As far as i know doesnt output inline css? And i still wonder how to do this using twigs :)

Comment: If you are not going to modify the file then why are you directly include in twig while you can do the same thing as @sekharctc mentioned!

Comment: Been 4 years, hope my comment seems not relevant :D